# Are these two Go pieces of code equivalent?

Tags: go

Having this struct

```
type Square struct {
    Side int
}
```

Are these to functions equivalent?

```
func (s *Square) SetSide(side int) {
    s.Side = side
}
```

vs

```
func SetSquareSide(s *Square, side int) {
    s.Side = side
}
```

I know they *do* the same, but are they really equivalent? I mean, is there any internal difference or something?

Try online: https://play.golang.org/p/gpt2KmsVrz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These "function" the same way, and in reality they are called in nearly the same way. The method is called as a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions), with the receiver as the first argument:

```
var s Square

// The method call
s.SetSide(5)
// is equivalent to the method expression
(*Square).SetSide(&s, 5)
```

The `SetSide` method can also be used as a [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) to satisfy the function signature `func(int)`, where as the `SetSquareSide` cannot.

```
var f func(int)

f = a.SetSide
f(9)
```

This is on top of the obvious fact that the method set of `Square` satisfies the interface

```
interface {
    SetSide(int)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know they work the same way.

One difference is that only the first one could satisfy an interface specification.